# How to downgrade EF power tools?

Tags: ef-power-tools

I had EF power tool extension installed in VS 2019. Recently it was auto upgraded to latest version to 2.5.649.
I have .NET Core 2.2 application that is using `microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver 2.2.6`
I am trying to use reverse engineering to create entities.
1> SQL table names are pluralize
2> Primary Key in the table ends with `ID`

I would like:
1>Corresponding entity name to be singularize.
2>Use columns names directly from the database. (keep `ID` as `ID`. Not change to `Id`)

This use to work with old version. As per latest [doc](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/) `For EF Core reverse engineering, .NET Core 3.1 x64 runtime must be installed`

**Questions**
1> Is it possible to get EF tools working with .NET Core 2.2?
2> If not, then is it possible to downgrade EF Tool?